# Variable not defined Python

Tags: python, syntax

I was trying to make a certain code and it keeps on giving me a syntax error :

> "File "N:/piethorn/Introduction to Python Workbook/file
>   handling/challenge.py", line 5, in  
>       string = str(string + character)
>   NameError: name 'string' is not defined"

The original code is:

```
> f = open("temp","r")   
f.seek(0)  
character = str(f.read(1))  
if character !=" ":  
>     string = str(string + character)  
>     character = f.read(1)  
else:  
>     print(string)  
>     f.close
```

Comment: You did not define `string` before the loop.

Comment: string variable is not defined. the error message is clear I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `string`. As obvious from the error message, `string` is out of scope for `else` block. Revised code should be:-

```
> f = open("temp","r")   
f.seek(0)  
character = str(f.read(1))  
string = ''
if character !=" ":  
>     string = str(string + character)  
>     character = f.read(1)  
else:  
>     print(string)  
>     f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("temp","r")   
f.seek(0)   
string ="" # definition
character = str(f.read(1))  
if character !=" ":  
 string = str(string + character)  # definition
 character = f.read(1)  
else:  
 print(string)  # usage
 f.close()
```

In `else` no `string` is being defined. It's the same as just `print string` without any previous definition as if `character` is equal to `" "` there's no `string` defined in `else`.

---

Moreover, you're using a variable called `string` while there's a Python module called `string`. You'd better rename your variable somehow, like `String`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining a `string` variable in Program

```
  f = open("temp","r")   
  f.seek(0)  
  string=""
  character = str(f.read(1))  
  if character !=" ":  
       string = str(string + character)  
       character = f.read(1)  
  else:  
       print(string)  
       f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

just define `string` as an empty string first:

```
f = open("temp","r")   
f.seek(0)  
character = str(f.read(1))  
string = ""
if character !=" ":  
     string = str(string + character)  
     character = f.read(1)  
else:  
     print(string)  
     f.close
print(string)
```